# Selected ListView items become unselected automatically

Tags: android, listview

I just created a ListView that is backed by a CursorLoader and when items in the ListView are clicked, they remain highlighted.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My issue is that in another fragment, I edit some data that makes changes to the internal database, and it seems that once my SyncAdapter runs, the selected item becomes unselected automatically. Does anyone have any experience with such problems?

EDIT:

Here's the code for the Fragment:

```
public class BidItemsFragment extends ListFragment implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

public static final String ITEM_TYPE_BIDITEM= "B";

private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
private ListView mList;
private Context mContext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContext = getActivity();
    fillData();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.biditems_list, container, false);
    mList = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return v;
}

private void fillData() {

    String[] from = new String[] { Columns.COLUMN_ITEMNUMBER };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.biditem_num };
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.biditems_row, null, from, to, 0);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    String[] projection = Columns.getColumns(RawContract.PARAM_SEBIDITEM);
    String selection = Columns.COLUMN_SYSID + "=?";
    String selectionArgs[] = { "1" };
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(mContext,
            BidProvider.CONTENT_URI_SEBIDITEM, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your adapter code

Comment: Basically you have to save state of your item to somewhere else. Maybe database, maybe hashmap or something like that. So it will remember if it was checked or no

Comment: I am just using a SimpleCursorAdapter. I was thinking something similar but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: There is nothing to do with your XML file, if you post your code for fragment/activity it would be better. In your onItemClick method you will have position, save this position and boolean value to somewhere else. You are trying to make it like radio button right? In the list you will have only one item selectable?

Comment: Yes, like a radio button. In the xml, the choiceMode="singleChoice" indicates that only one item can be selected at a time. The fragment is fairly simple: it is a CursorLoader that gets data from a local database and a SimpleCursorAdapter that maps the data to the list. I was more interested in why this happens when my SyncAdapter runs

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I updated the post with the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35452/discussion-between-gokhan-arik-and-user1549672)